# Heroku toolbelt fails to run after last update

Tags: heroku

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10.

Heroku stopped working COMPLETELY after last update (last run of 'heroku update'). Now EVERY command results in:

/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:54:in `inject_libpath': undefined local variable or method`lib' for Heroku::Updater:Module (NameError)
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:53:in `each'
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:53:in`inject_libpath'
from /usr/bin/heroku:24

Updated - Solution:
Saw some warnings here about re-installing heroku, but support just had me re-install and it fixed the issue and everything seems to be working just fine:

apt-get remove heroku-toolbelt

apt-get install heroku-toolbelt

Comment: Which version do you have installed now?

Comment: @JBN Hey, glad you got this fixed! You should consider pasting your solution in the Answer box below and marking your own answer as the 'accepted answer' - this will help other Stack Overflow users see that your question has been solved. See [this FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/189918) for more information.

Comment: Try installing the `heroku gem` instead of the toolbelt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you install the Heroku toolbelt again it should work.