# heroku update error

Tags: ruby, macos, heroku, osx-lion

After I updated heroku, when I try to update heroku again:

```
$ heroku update
/Users/ohho/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/update.rb:14:in `index': undefined method `disable' for Heroku::Updater:Module (NoMethodError)
from /Users/ohho/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:148:in `run'
from /usr/bin/heroku:27:in `<main>'
```

How can I fix it?

```
$ heroku status
All Systems Go: No known issues at this time.
$ heroku version
2.25.0
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.12.3 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it and it worked for me.  I'm on Snow Leopard, Ruby 1.9.3p290.  It updated to 2.25.0.  Found this SO link
[Heroku toolbelt fails to run after last update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8899029/1308014)

even though it is for Ubuntu.  Basically they removed and reinstalled the heroku-toolbelt.

Comment: Un-installed (`rm -rf /usr/loca/heroku`; `sudo rm /usr/bin/heroku`) and re-installed heroku fixed the issue.