# Heroku throws error when deploying my app. Can't make sense of it

Tags: heroku

My GIT commit and push commands go through successfully, but my application fails to start, and tells me there has been a server error. I have checked the Heroku server status and it is operating at optimum performance.

Here is the error I found in my logs:

```
C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/updater.rb:155
:in `spawn': No such file or directory - C:/Program Files/Heroku/bin/heroku upda
te (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/u
pdater.rb:155:in `background_update!'
        from C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:135:in `inject_libpat
h'
        from C:/Program Files/Heroku/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

I don't understand what this means. Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you install the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/)?

Comment: yes, I installed it, and catch this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the 2.32.13 version. Removing this version and installing the 2.32.14 solved the issue on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899029/heroku-toolbelt-fails-to-run-after-last-update) (on Ubuntu) removing and installing should fix the problem

Comment: Let me try it out and report back

Comment: I reinstalled the toolbeit, and now even my heroku login throws the same error.

Comment: did you remove all your config files and the toolbelt files

Comment: I uninstalled Heroku toolbelt from the Add/Remove Programs. What else should I delete?