# heroku fails to work (update error)

Tags: heroku

My heroku suddenly stopped working. I got this message over and over again when running heroku.bat with any command line:

> C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:155:in `spawn': No such file or directory - C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku update (Errno::ENOENT)
>           from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:155:in`background_update!'
>           from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:135:in `inject_libpath'

I tried to reinstall, and delete %userprofile%.heroku but nothing works.. I'm using Windows 7 64 bit.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku throws error when deploying my app. Can't make sense of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910031/heroku-throws-error-when-deploying-my-app-cant-make-sense-of-it)

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Just downloaded Heroku for the first time today. Tried reinstalling as well!

Comment: I guess they have a problem with their update mechanism. I tried to edit updater.rb and comment out the lines that do the update but the file is locked:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think version 2.32.13 was bugged tried reinstalling it to no avail. I've redownloaded and got 2.32.14 reinstalling now...